# Fill between 4 points: Matplotlib won't let me add more points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a bounding box. I have all the coordinates. Now, I need to fill between this space. No matter, what combination I try, it won't let me set a limit on `y`.

**What I have:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
plt.imshow(np.random.randint(0, 255, (1200, 1200, 3)))

plt.fill_between([1080, 1120], [800, 800], color='blue', alpha=.5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

**What I need:**

[image]

The `y` axis needs to stop around 200.

Comment: You didn't specify 200 anywhere, like `plt.fill_between([1080, 1120], [800, 800],[200,200])`. But in order to make a rectangle you could also just add one like `plt.gca().add_patch(plt.Rectangle((1080, 200), 40, 600))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should allow you to do what you want to achieve.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
plt.imshow(np.random.randint(0, 255, (1200, 1200, 3)))

left_upper_corner = (200, 300)
width = 400
height = 150

rectangle = matplotlib.patches.Rectanglr(left_upper_corner, width, height, fill=“blue“, alpha=.5)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html), the signature for this function is    `matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between(x, y1, y2=0, where=None, interpolate=False, step=None, *, data=None, **kwargs)`, where `x` is an array and `y1/y2` is an array or scalar. You give an array for `x` and `y1`, but never `y2`.

Using `plt.fill_between([1080, 1120], 200, 800, color='blue', alpha=.5)` should give the result you are looking for.